# Graph 2 variable function as surface

Tags: matlab, function, graph, surface

I'm new to Matlab, and I was wondering how you might graph a two-variable function as a surface graph, like `sin(x)/y^(log(x))`. Say I create two ranges, `x` and `y`, both represented by the range `-4:0.001:4`, and want to graph the above function as a surface. How would I go about doing it?

Comment: I assume you've tried `surf`, which is the first hit in Google for "Matlab surface graph" and worked through all of the [examples here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/creating-mesh-and-surface-plots.html)?

Comment: I have, and have also watched a few tutorial videos, but I was wondering how I would use two separate variables. In this example it looks like they use a 'meshgrid'; any idea how I would transform two distinct variables into a single meshgrid?

Comment: Yes, `meshgrid` will be pretty useful. I bet if you read through the documentation for the function and try some things you'll learn a lot and even get it to work. As it stands, your question is a low quality "do it for me" type. You should show your code; what you tried. Indicate exactly what is not working, any error messages in their entirety, and what you expected the output to be.

Comment: You should see if you get similar plot using `meshgrid`. That is homework :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ezsurf` to plot the surface defined by a two-variable function. Of course, this can be done by `surf` as well by manually defining the `(x,y)` grid.

```
ezsurf('sin(x)/y^(log(x))')
```

[image: Plotting a surface defined by two variables]